# Pattern Matching misspelled Strings

Tags: javascript, pattern-matching

I oftentimes need to check for certain strings on a webpage, that are not necessarily spelled absolutely the same. For example, sometimes I screen a page for a string like ***google***, then on other pages I want it to match against, let's say: ***gooogle*** or ***Google Inc.***.

Where to start in terms of pattern-matching and algorithms?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance

Answer (score 1):

for theory:
search for edit-distance:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edit_distance

and n-gram:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/N-gram

Here is an actual framework which provides those functionalities:
[fuzzyset.js](http://glench.github.io/fuzzyset.js/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, will look into those

Comment: or in general, search for "fuzzy search"